# TextView and EditText in single Row in Android?

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

I am writing XML in following way, list_item2 contains TextView and EditText, while list_item is another XML contains only TextView,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/textItem"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp" >
</TextView>

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</EditText>
```

I am using the xml in ListView, such as

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row;

        if(position!=2) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }
        else {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item2, parent, false);
        }
        TextView tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textItem);
        tv.setText(getItem(position));

        tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

but It is creating output like

```
 TextView

 EditText
```

I want both on same row, such as

```
   TextView        EditText
```

Any one edit the XML and let me know the hierarchy for creating GUI in Android Apps

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take your `EditText` and `TextView` inside a `LinearLayout` having horizontal orientation (which is applied by default) and set `layout_weight = 1` or whatever do you want to `EditText` and `TextView`

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<TextView android:id="@+id/textItem"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"/ >
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @Aadil Soomro, I was searching for you in form chat rooms :-P

Comment: mostly I'm available in [Casual Chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1531/casual-chat)

Comment: I have upvoted, and answer can be acceptable after 5 mints, so I will accept it too Dear

Comment: @AdilSoomro if i want to do for more than 1 rows like in app registration screen.

Comment: @SunishthaSingh take another `LinearLayout` and set its orientation to vertical. and inside add multiple above `LinearLayouts`.

Answer (score 2):

use following layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lnrTitle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textItem"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weight="1"
        android:textSize="16sp" >
    </TextView>

        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:weight="1"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @bindal-android:orientation="vertical"?

Comment: @bindal-NO worries:) +1 for the effort:)

Answer (score 1):

Add one parent Layout say a LinearLayout to your xml like this:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal" > 
<TextView android:id="@+id/textItem"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:textSize="16sp" >
</TextView>
<EditText
android:id="@+id/editText1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:orientation="horizontal"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:padding="10dp">

     <TextView android:id="@+id/textItem"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:padding="10dp"
         android:textSize="16sp" >
     </TextView>

     <EditText
         android:id="@+id/editText1"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
     </EditText>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice and fast solution adopted today by many applications,
add this tags to your TextView

```
android:ellipsize="end"
android:maxLines="1"
```

Now your textview is one row with three dots to the end.